# Draw a graphic structure with JSF

Tags: jsf, structure, paint, mindmap, organizational-chart

I would like to create a JSF web application to **display** a graphic structure (composed of hierarchical elements organised in a database) where, if possible, the user could eventually zoom in/out, add new elements...

But I haven't been able to identify a single JSF component (or compatible component) to help me do that.

This is what I would like : http://www.yworks.com/products/yfileshtml/demos/Complete/demo.yfiles.graph.orgchart/index.html
But it's not free and not in JSF.

I thought of the PrimeFaces mindmap component, but it is not compatible with IE8 and this is a requirement for my projet...

My second thought was to use RichFaces' Paint2D to manually draw info in rectangles and links between rectangles with calculated coordinates, but this seems a bit complex...
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/paint2D.jsf?c=paint2d

A final thought was to use CSS to display rectangles, but I can't display links and interact with the structure...

Any better idea ?
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

OmniFaces has [a component for creating a hierarchical tree](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree).
Maybe you could use that to display a custom markup, and work out a way to manipulate it with Javascript, in order to get the behavior you want.

If that is not feasible, I'd suggest you to study a little bit of HTML5 Canvas, see what you can do with that. You can get inspired here checking out [this is open source (GPL) HTML5 mind map app](http://drichard.org/mindmaps/), the [code is at GitHub](https://github.com/drichard/mindmaps).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately the hierarchical tree isn't exactly what I need, it's still too much tabular.

As for the HTML5 mind map app, it requires IE9+ :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that... IE compatibility is quite a struggle.